# Keyboard shortcut is not working in Fullscreen on VLC Media Player

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, vlc

Recently I made a clean install of ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop. After updating the OS I installed VLC Media Player. Whenever I go to fullscreen in VLC the keyboard shortcutss don't seems to work. For example "space" button doesn't seem to pause the video from playing. But it works if its not fullscreened. I previously used 12.04 and 14.04 and there was no problem. But this new version is giving me a headache. Is there a solution to this???
Edit: One thing I'd like to add. If I fullscreen VLC by double clicking in the video, pause the video with mouse than the problem appears. I cant seem to play that video by simply touching the spacebar button. I had to do with mouse.

Comment: Are you sure the window is focused after you put it in full screen?

Comment: Yes. I just checked that. That's not the problem.

Comment: I have this problem with VLC 3.0, but 2.2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In full screen mode focus switch to controls panel. Try to disable it in Tools -> Preferences -> Show controls in full screen mode. Works for me (vlc 3.0.10).